# How Can I Animate My Picasso Placeholder

Tags: android, animation, picasso

I'm currently loading my image, but there's no animation, just my plain image inside my `ImageView` on Picasso's Placeholder.

And here's my question: **How can I make a my Picasso's placeholder animated?**

*This is what I've got by now in my .xml file*

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:drawable="@mipmap/loading"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:toDegrees="360"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

*Implementation on Activity's Code:*

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(ApiEndpointInterface.BASE_URL +
                application.getUser().getAvatar().getHdpi().getUrl())
                .transform(new CropCircleTransformation(250, 2, getApplicationContext()))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.animation_progress)
                .into(UserImageField);
```

Note: `animated-rotate` it's not working for me, the animation doesn't go fluidly.